# How to extend an object from another object based on values referred?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays where each element is an object:

```
var cars = [{
  brand: "VW",
  brand_id: "1",
  models: [
    {
      name: "Golf",
      model_id: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "Passat",
      model_id: "2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  brand: "BMW",
  brand_id: "2",
  models: [
    {
      name: "X3",
      model_id: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "X5",
      model_id: "2"
    }
  ]
}];

var drivers = [{
  name: "Test Driver",
  cars: [
    {
      brand_id: "1",
      model_id: "1"
    },
    {
      brand_id: "2",
      model_id: "1"
    }
  ]
}]
```

What is the best way to copy the model's name into the car object for each driver? This is the expected result:

```
var drivers = [{
  name: "Test",
  cars: [
    {
      brand_id: "1",
      model_id: "1",
      name: "Golf"
    },
    {
      brand_id: "2",
      model_id: "1",
      name: "X3"
    }
  ]
}]
```

My idea was loop through the drivers, then loop through the cars for each driver, then loop through each cars, then loop... so much loops. I hope theres an easier way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid loops here due to the data structure. But you can do it in a fairly clean way

```js
var cars = [{"brand":"VW","brand_id":"1","models":[{"name":"Golf","model_id":"1"},{"name":"Passat","model_id":"2"}]},{"brand":"BMW","brand_id":"2","models":[{"name":"X3","model_id":"1"},{"name":"X5","model_id":"2"}]}];
var drivers = [{"name":"Test Driver","cars":[{"brand_id":"1","model_id":"1"},{"brand_id":"2","model_id":"1"}]}];

drivers.forEach(expandCars);

function expandCars(driver) {
  // map each car to list of car brands filtered by brand ID
  // then to resulting list of car models by model ID
  driver.cars = driver.cars.map(car => {
     var carModels = cars.filter(carBrand => carBrand.brand_id == car.brand_id)[0].models;
     var model = carModels.filter(carModel => carModel.model_id == car.model_id)[0];
    
     return Object.assign(car, model);
  });
}



console.log(drivers);
```

Honestly this data structure seems needlessly complex. Why is `cars` a list of Brands, and each Brand has a list of Models? Why not have the `cars` array look like the `driver.cars` array, just a flat list where each object has the Brand and Model? This would make searching the structure for cars much easier. `ModelID` should be unique across brands too, so you can just check the model ID and know that the brand must be the same if the model is the same.

Comment: Thanks! The data structure is actually completely different(in content), just tried to simplify it for an example and used cars/brands/models.

Comment: Instead of using `filter` and taking the first element of the result, these days `find` is often preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two `forEach()`loops, to loop each object in drivers array and then cars array inside current object. After that you can use two `find()` loops to find object in cars array with same `brand_id` and then inside models find object with same `model_id` and return `name`.

```js
var cars = [{"brand":"VW","brand_id":"1","models":[{"name":"Golf","model_id":"1"},{"name":"Passat","model_id":"2"}]},{"brand":"BMW","brand_id":"2","models":[{"name":"X3","model_id":"1"},{"name":"X5","model_id":"2"}]}];
var drivers = [{"name":"Test Driver","cars":[{"brand_id":"1","model_id":"1"},{"brand_id":"2","model_id":"1"}]}];

drivers.forEach(function(e) {
  e.cars.forEach(function(c) {
    c.name = cars.find(function(a) {
      return a.brand_id == c.brand_id;
    }).models.find(function(a) {
      return c.model_id == a.model_id;
    }).name
  })
})

console.log(drivers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the cars and assign later the name.

```js
var cars = [{ brand: "VW", brand_id: "1", models: [{ name: "Golf", model_id: "1" }, { name: "Passat", model_id: "2" }] }, { brand: "BMW", brand_id: "2", models: [{ name: "X3", model_id: "1" }, { name: "X5", model_id: "2" }] }],
    drivers = [{ name: "Test Driver", cars: [{ brand_id: "1", model_id: "1" }, { brand_id: "2", model_id: "1" }] }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

cars.forEach(function (brands) {
    brands.models.forEach(function (model) {
        hash[[brands.brand_id, model.model_id].join('|')] = model;
    });
});

drivers.forEach(function (driver) {
    driver.cars.forEach(function (car) {
        car.name = hash[[car.brand_id, car.model_id].join('|')].name;
    });
});

console.log(drivers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `Array.prototype.reduce` along with a hash table - see demo below:

```js
var cars=[{brand:"VW",brand_id:"1",models:[{name:"Golf",model_id:"1"},{name:"Passat",model_id:"2"}]},{brand:"BMW",brand_id:"2",models:[{name:"X3",model_id:"1"},{name:"X5",model_id:"2"}]}];
var drivers=[{name:"Test Driver",cars:[{brand_id:"1",model_id:"1"},{brand_id:"2",model_id:"1"}]}];

var result = drivers.reduce(function(hash) {

  // create a hash table first
  cars.forEach(function(element) {
    element.models.forEach(function(model) {
      hash[element.brand_id + "|" + model.model_id] = model.name;
    });
  });

  // now reduce it to obtain the result
  return function(prev, curr) {
    curr.cars.forEach(function(element) {
      element.name = hash[element.brand_id + "|" + element.model_id];
    });
    prev.push(curr);
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: @passatgt let me know your feedback on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
drivers.cars.forEach(                                
  car =>                                             
    car.name =                                       
      cars.find(                                     
        car2 =>                                      
          car2.brand_id === car.brand_id             
      )
        .models.find(                                
          model => 
            model.model_id === car.model_id
        ).name
)
```

In English:

> Set the name of each car in the cars list in the drivers object to the result of first looking up the car in the cars object with the right brand, and then finding the model within that car where the model_id matches, and taking its name.